# Change the class in a div based on window size (jQuery/JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the class of my list based on the window size.

This is my div at the moment:

```
<div>
    <ul id="image-holder" class="list-inline acc-list">
        <li><img src="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the screen is resized to a small size (i.e. mobile/tablet) I would like it to change the div to the following:

```
<div>
    <ul id="image-holder" class="imageslider">
        <li><img src="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried the following JavaScript so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var $window = $(window);

    // Function to handle changes to style classes based on window width
    function checkWidth() {
        if ($window.width() < 980) {
            $('#image-holder').removeClass('acc-list').removeClass('list-inline').addClass('bxslider');
        };

        if ($window.width() >= 980) {
            $('#image-holder').removeClass('bxslider').addClass('acc-list').addClass('list-inline');
        }
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();

    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);

    $('.imageslider').imageSlider({
        slideWidth: 188,
        slideHeight: 188,
        slideMargin: 0,
        auto: true
    });
});
```

This works if the window is ALREADY at a certain size, but upon resizing it doesn't successfully change between the imageslider being active and inactive.

Chrome Inspector:

```
<ul id="image-holder" class="acc-list list-inline" style="-webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);">
    <li style="width: 100px;">
        <img src="img/image1.png" alt="">
        <div class="acc-desc-container">
            <p class="desc">blablabla</p>
            <p class="price">blablalba</p>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: That's because the imageSlider plugin probably only runs on elements that actually match the selector, so adding the class later doesn't matter, and initializing the plugin on every resize seems like a bad idea, so you probably can't do that (or at least shouldn't).

Comment: @adeneo I did think this, it seems I would have to effectively reload the page every time to re-detect whether or not to use the `imageslider` tag. What do you think is the best way to implement this? I basically want my images to load themselves into an imageslider when the window is small

Comment: I think the best way to go is to rewrite the plugin to work how you want, anything else is probably going to have issues, but I don't know how this imageSlider plugin works, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @adeneo the plugin I am using is bxSlider (bxslider.com) but I definitely don't have the JS expertise to rewrite the behaviour of the plugin unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be something like this, starting in your document.ready:

after

> var $window = $(window);

add:

```
var rslider;
function createSlider() {
    rslider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 188,
    slideHeight: 188,
    slideMargin: 0,
    auto: true
        });
};
```

and then change your `checkWidth()` function to something like:

```
function checkWidth() {
    if ($window.width() < 980) {
        $('#image-holder').addClass('bxslider');            
        if ($('#image-holder').hasClass('acc-list') && $('#image-holder').hasClass('list-inline') && $('#image-holder').hasClass('bxslider')) {
            createSlider();}
       $('#image-holder').removeClass('acc-list').removeClass('list-inline');
    };

    if ($window.width() >= 980) {
        if ($('#image-holder').hasClass('bxslider')) {
            rslider.destroySlider();}
        $('#image-holder').removeClass('bxslider').addClass('acc-list').addClass('list-inline');
   }
}
```

This will add (once), and then destroy(once) the slider as the screen moves.
It creates a global rslider variable to store the slider in, and I removed the `.imageSlider`, since it did not match the rest of the code, and since you already call `checkWidth()` to create the slider.

[Here's a fiddle with bxslider 4.12](http://jsfiddle.net/9jmpg/)

Comment: Hi @Mike this works excellently, the only issue is that when I scale the window back up to full size, the layout of the 3 images is messed up, so the 3 images are all overlapping and go off the page for some reason, do you have any idea?

Comment: @germainelol - I don't know the size of the images or the css or html or other code on the images or the page. When I put images in the fiddle, they don't overlap or go off the page. So I'm guessing it's something related to the rest of the code. You could try forking the fiddle and adding code to it until it has the same error, maybe that would help?

Comment: Not sure how I can provide a fiddle as I'm using bootstrap and my files are quite big at the minute. I can show you the code, but I can tell you the images are 188x188. `list-inline` is a bootstrap feature and `acc-list` only has `float: left` inside

Comment: @germainelol - none of those things would cause the images to overlap or go off the page - I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jmpg/1/) here with those changes. So it has to be something else in the code.

Comment: I am definitely at a loss then

Comment: Can't seem to find anything that would mess it up

Comment: @germainelol - try taking a look in chrome inspector or firefox firebug and see what classes are being applied to the images or li's or ul's and which ones would affect it. It's possible that you have a `position: absolute` or a `top:` or `left:` something somewhere.

Comment: I have added the code from Chrome's inspector to the original post.

Comment: I see the `<li>`'s are being changed to a width of 100px, but for the life of me I can't see how or why

Comment: I found that it is `element.style {width: 100px;}` which is making the `<li>` to change to 100px as when I remove this style on Chrome inspector the layout is fine. `element.style` isn't anywhere I can find though

Comment: @germainelol, well, unfortunately, without seeing the code, I don't think that there is much else I can do. `element.style` is generally set by javascript somewhere. It almost looks like the slider isn't being completely destroyed, or is being partially created somewhere, or has a `slideWidth:100px` set somewhere.

Comment: Can I show you the code? The only way I can think of fixing it is to apply a class to all `<li>`'s with a fixed width and padding, but this would most likely cause issues when activating/deactivating the slider.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56833/discussion-between-germainelol-and-mike).